# Change design of the bottom html video menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, video, html5-video

My code is as below:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
video {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<video width="400" controls>
  <source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>

<p>Resize the browser window to see how the size of the video player will scale.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

By using the code above, I get the design below:
[image]

How can i change the design of the menu highlighted in the image? For example,
I want to change the design of the play button as well as add a full screen view button.

Answer (score 3):

Don't you think using a HTML5 player is a better option than manually styling your design? HTML5 players like video.js and Meisterplayer are customizable. However, it depends on how much you wanna customize. [Here](http://www.creativebloq.com/html5/build-custom-html5-video-player-9134473) is an example of customizing the player.

Answer (score 2):

First, please refer to [this site](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/building-custom-controls-for-html5-videos). I'm not going to list the whole coding, please take a look by yourself.

You may build a custom control bar by yourself and just place it under the video.

**HTML**

```
<div id="video-container">
  <!-- Video -->
  <video id="video" width="640" height="365"></video> //your video
  <!-- Video Controls -->
  <div id="video-controls">
    <button type="button" id="play-pause">Play</button>
    <input type="range" id="seek-bar" value="0">
    <button type="button" id="mute">Mute</button>
    <input type="range" id="volume-bar" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="1">
    <button type="button" id="full-screen">Full-Screen</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then, using javascript to get each button or tag. Like
`var fullScreenButton = document.getElementById("full-screen");` and add the function.

**Full screen function**

```
fullScreenButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (video.requestFullscreen) {
    video.requestFullscreen();
  } else if (video.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    video.mozRequestFullScreen(); // Firefox
  } else if (video.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
    video.webkitRequestFullscreen(); // Chrome and Safari
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit more complicated than just changing a style.

I'd suggest taking a look at Tyler Fry's video player on `CodePen` (`https://codepen.io/frytyler/pen/juGfk`) to get an idea of all you can do.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the controls of the  element can’t be stylized using CSS.

To do that, you will need to use a combination of *JavaScript*, *CSS* and *HTML5 Media API*.

Read [here](http://mrbool.com/how-to-style-the-html-5-video-element-with-javascript-and-css/27683) to make custom video player.